# how to set Listview height dynamically having multiline textview inside item in android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, textview, multiline

I am using code given at many places-

```
public void setListHeight(ListView list, CustomListPairingAdapter adapter, int screenRatio)
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int _hieght = size.y;
        if (adapter != null) {
             int totalHeight = 0;
                 for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                     View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, list);
                     listItem.measure(0, 0);
                     totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                 }

                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = list.getLayoutParams();
                 totalHeight=totalHeight + (list.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount()));
                int desiredHeight=_hieght*screenRatio/100;
                 if(desiredHeight<=totalHeight)
                 params.height = desiredHeight;
                 else
                     params.height = totalHeight;

                 list.setLayoutParams(params);
                 list.requestLayout();
            }
    }
```

But it does not work when list item has multiline textview. How to resolve this problem. any ideas ?
Thanks already

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code. Its very hard to understand without it. Also add what is not working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myHeight=20;
LayoutParams par=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
                 (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myHeight); 
//Replace RelativeLayout with the parent layout of list view

ListView t=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
t.setLayoutParams(par);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this custom listview to avoid listhieght having multiline textview problem

```
 <namespace.epicurio.NestedListView
       android:id="@+id/listComments"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
       android:divider="#000000"
       android:dividerHeight="1.0sp">
     </namespace.epicurio.NestedListView>


public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnTouchListener, OnScrollListener {

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```